# Searching the registry for a string in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to do a query on the registry for uninstallation of a program but dont know where to start.

The structure would be like so:

`If {123-456-789}` exisits in registry then run

```
 Msi.exe /x {123-456-789}
```

Otherwise run

```
 Msi.exe /x {987-654-321}
```

Does anyone have any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from here :-)

"Reading from and Writing to the Registry"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85t3c3hf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Check how RegistryKey / Registry / RegistryHive class works,
Take a starting point (in the registry), then enumerate all the key/subkey/value, and compare the string/value found to check if they are what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm, thanks.  Is there a more elegant way of checking what version of the software is installed rather than searching the registry?

Comment: I don't know. it depends from the software you are analyzing, and what can you use to differentiate the various version of this software. Maybe you can check the version of the executable... but then you need to fine the path of the executable.

Answer (score 1):

https://superuser.com/questions/65714/how-can-i-search-the-windows-registry-with-regular-expressions googling for this - I found this article.. the exporting it idea might work for you?

Also this guy seems to do what you need.
http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/vb-net-general-discussion/38567-regex-visual-basic-net-2005-case-insensitive-registry-search.html

Comment: Hmm, thanks.  Is there a more elegant way of checking what version of the software is installed rather than searching the registry?